# Build com maven não encontra lib no Artifacts

Tags: microsoft-azure

Estou criar uma pipeline no Azure DevOps para buildar projetos java com maven.

Ao tentar fazer os downloads das libs no Artifacts aparece o seguinte erro

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException:
>   Could not find artifact com.oracle:ojdbc14:jar:10.2.0.4.0 in
>   azure.maven.XXX.com.br

Mas ao consultar no Artifacts eu encontro a lib

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o que fazer para o Maven encontrar essa lib?

Answer (score 1):

Pela mensagem de erro, o Maven não está encontrando os pacotes do Maven Central.

Pra isso funcionar você precisa configurar o Maven Central como *upstream* do seu feed no Artifacts.

Você pode verificar se essa configurações nas configurações do seu feed, *Upstream sources* > *Add upstream source*

Selecione em seguida a opção *Select a feed URL* e selecione o Maven Central.

Referencia: [Use packages from Maven Central](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/maven/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Obrigado por Responder , eu tentei fazer o que você falou , funcionou para todos os outros artefatos exceto para os da oracle, Para resolver o problema eu fiz uma Solução Alternativa provisoriamente fixa (Gambiarra ) que consiste em  subir a lib do oracle para um repo aparte e na hora do build usar
 <dependency>
 <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}/src/jar/ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>